# Table Reference in Formula Changes When Worksheets Copied

Tags: vba, excel, copy, listobject

I have two sheets in "Property" Workbook that I am copying to "UQP" Workbook.

> **PropertyCoverage** - Houses formula `=VLOOKUP("PF",tPremium,2,0)` among other text and simple SUM formula.
>
> **xmlProperty** - Houses table `tPremium` (among other tables; all tables mapped to XML Source)

When I copy these two sheets (simultaneously) into the UQP workbook the `tPremium` reference in the formula in the PropertyCoverage sheet automatically changes to `tAutoForms`, which is another table in the UQP workbook (that has nothing to do with the formula). UQP workbook has several other sheets and tables.

I don't know why this changes automatically, but I think it has something to do with the fact that Excel cannot copy multiples sheets when at least one sheet contains a table.

I have tried the solution below (referenced from [here](https://blogs.office.com/2009/08/31/copying-worksheets-with-a-list-or-table/)). However, the same issue happens. The issue does not happen if I copy to a new workbook. ... *Bear with ActiveWorkbook, etc, I only used this as test to see if it would work*

```
Sub Copy_Worksheets()

    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Set wbMaster = Workbooks("UniversalQuoteProposal.xlsb")
    Dim TheActiveWindow As Window
    Dim TempWindow As Window
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set TheActiveWindow = ActiveWindow
        Set TempWindow = .NewWindow
        .Sheets(Array("PropertyCoverage", "xmlProperty")).Copy Before:=wbMaster.Worksheets(1)
    End With
    TempWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Here is my original copy code:

```
Sub CopySheetsToMaster()

Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Set wbMaster = Workbooks("UniversalQuoteProposal.xlsb")

Dim sSheetName As String
sSheetName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsb", "")

Dim sSheets As Variant
sSheets = Array(sSheetName & "Coverage", "xml" & sSheetName)

'*** => This is where tPremium gets automatically changed to tAutoForms
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sSheets).Copy Before:=wbMaster.Worksheets(1)

wbMaster.ChangeLink ThisWorkbook.FullName, wbMaster.FullName, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks

End Sub
```

Lastly, I can work around this by doing a Replace after the sheets are copied, but since this will scale out to a need to bring a possible 7-10 other workbooks with potential formula references to tables and such, I would rather find a cleaner solution if it exists.

Lastly, I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: Presumably it works OK if you copy the sheets one at a time?

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - Hmm. Didn't try that obvious test :) Will try and let you know.

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem using Excel 2013

Comment: I am on 2010 @CharlesWilliams. Perhaps the "bug" was fixed in 2013?

Comment: Works OK for me in XL2010

Comment: Note my test does not use tables mapped to an XML source - they are just ordinary tables.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - Did you copy into a workbook that had existing tables already?

Comment: Yes UQP workbook has a tAutoForms table

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - I tested for one sheet at a time and the behavior is to bring the Workbook name along with the table name .. so `MyWorkbook!tPremium`. It leaves it there after I change the link source, too. If I find and replace the the workbook name, it automatically transfers to the new workbook. This suggestion helped because replacing the workbook name has more scalability than the the table name. Overall, I have a feeling it's due to the XML mapping behind the table that is causing the issue since the XML mapping will not be coming with the transfer.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - Lastly, thanks for giving it a test drive.